# ¿Cómo revierto una contraseña hash md5 con php?

Tags: php

Esta es una tarea que me dejaron como practica y no he podido resolverla. La forma de hacerlo según me lo indican es que debo hacer una "fuerza bruta" la cual hace 10,000 combinaciones para obtener el PIN de 4 dígitos de 5 hash md5 que ponen para realizar dicha tarea. Es decir que debo pasar a través de un formulario html de tipo texto, una contraseña encriptada por hash md5 y que esta devuelva un PIN de 4 dígitos.

El avance que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    $gtext = "Not found";

    if (isset($_GET['md5'])) {
        $time_pre = microtime(true);
        $md5 = $_GET['md5'];

        $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        $show = 15;
            
        for($i=0; $i<strlen($alphabet); $i++ ) {
            $ch1 = $alphabet[$i];   


            for($j=0; $j<strlen($alphabet); $j++ ) {
                $ch2 = $alphabet[$j]; 
                $try = $ch1.$ch2;
                $check = hash('md5', $try);

                if ( $check == $md5 ) {
                    $gtext = $try;
                    break;  
                }
        
                if ( $show > 0 ) {
                    print "$check $try\n";
                    $show = $show - 1;
                }
            }
        }
           
        $time_post = microtime(true);
        print "Elapsed time: ";
        print $time_post-$time_pre;
        print "\n";
    }
    ?>
```

El cual lo que hace es usar dos bucles anidados y prueba las 26 * 26 combinaciones de dos letras minúsculas, y calcula los valores hash de esos valores y comprueba si el hash calculado coincide.

> NOTA: Por cierto el método GET lo utilizo porque me piden utilizarlo
> en las especificaciones de la tarea.

Para que se me pueda entender mejor, debo pasar los siguientes hash md5:

- 0bd65e799153554726820ca639514029
- aa36c88c27650af3b9868b723ae15dfc
- 1ca906c1ad59db8f11643829560bab55
- 1d8d70dddf147d2d92a634817f01b239
- acf06cdd9c744f969958e1f085554c8b

A PIN de 4 dígitos como lo dije anteriormente como en esta página que me dan de ejemplo: https://www.wa4e.com/solutions/crack/?PHPSESSID=fe17eaa527c89f9a0e1fbf4bb5218c70

> NOTA: Utilizo letras porque dentro de los ejemplos y pistas me lo planteaban (del curso) y pues ya intente con números de igual manera y el resultado es el mismo.

En cuanto al resultado siempre me devuelve "Not found" que es la variable que asigné al principio del código anterior para devolverlo en el caso de que no encontrara el hash.

Comment: Un hash MD5 no se desencripta. Comparas otras cadenas a las que le aplicas el hash, con un hash que ya tengas. MD5 es irrecuperable. Por como está diseñado el hash (la probabilidad de colisión y tal), es posible generar un mismo hash a partir de varias cadenas diferentes. Dicho esto sobre el título de la pregunta, no nos dices en niguna parte cuál es tu problema con tu algoritmo de fuerza bruta. ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: Bueno creo que no realice bien mi pregunta, no es como tal desencriptarla es como revertir el hash usando la técnica que nombro "fuerza bruta", en la que se reenvían todas las combinaciones posibles de caracteres en cadenas. En resumen necesito ayuda para que mi código haga lo que hace la página que anexé en lo último del texto.

Comment: El link funciona con valores numéricos de 4 dígitos y los md5 de la pregunta igual lo son. Por qué usas letras `$alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";` en el código?

Comment: CUál es el resultado actual? En qué podemos ayudarte? Qué error sale? Por favor, indícalo EN la pregunta. :)

Comment: Utilizo letras porque es una pista que me dieron dentro del curso que estoy haciendo (Ya probe con números y el resultado es el mismo). En cuanto al resultado pues siempre me sale "Not found" que es de la variable que asigno al comienzo del código.

Comment: La única forma en la que eso retorna `not found` es cuando el GET falla, es decir, cuando no haces `localhost?md5=0bd65e799153554726820ca639514029`. Lo probé quemándolo en la variable md5 y hace lo que dices que debe hacer. Pero bueh, eso es secundario al problema real. ¿Esencialmente hasta ahora tienes dos ciclos para validar cuatro campos y vas a poner cuatro ciclos anidados?

Comment: Quieres decir que debo agregar otros dos ciclos?, porque eso si no lo había pensado...

Comment: Acabo de agregar dos ciclos más y eso era el problema, no lo había pensado... Muchas gracias @Alfabravo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien dicen en los comentarios los hash son de 4 números no de letras. Podemos resolver el ejercicio con un solo bucle for ya que lo que buscamos es recorrer todos los posibles valores.

Ejemplo:

```php
<?php

$hash = '1d8d70dddf147d2d92a634817f01b239';
$key = '0000'; // donde empezamos a buscar
$end = '9999'; // donde terminamos de buscar


for($i = 1; $key <= $end; $i++) {
    //echo md5 ($key) . PHP_EOL;
    if ($hash == md5($key)) {
        break;
    }

    if($key == $end) {
       $key = 'No encontrado';
       break;
    }

    $key++;
}

echo md5 ($key) . PHP_EOL;
echo $key . PHP_EOL; // 4427
echo 'iteraciones: ' . $i; // 4428
```

El mismo código de arriba nos valdría para buscar string

Ejemplo:

```php
<?php

$hash = '65ba841e01d6db7733e90a5b7f9e6f80';
$key = 'aaaa';
$end = 'zzzz';


for($i = 1; $key <= $end; $i++) {
    //echo md5 ($key) . PHP_EOL;
    if ($hash == md5($key)) {
        break;
    }

    if($key == $end) {
       $key = 'No encontrado';
       break;
    }

    $key++;
}

echo md5 ($key) . PHP_EOL;
echo $key . PHP_EOL; //bbbb
echo 'iteraciones: ' . $i; // 18280
```

En el caso de tener conbinacion de mayúsculas y minúsculas o ser el alfanumérico  estos for simples ya no nos valdrían y deberíamos añadir algún código extra.